# How can I determine what causes repeated Windows Installer self-repair?

Tags: package-management, windows-installer, reinstall, msi

The **Windows Installer Service** keeps triggering a **repair operation** (**self-repair**) of a package installed on my desktop. I am unable to find the cause and resolve the problem permanently.

How do I find out what is triggering the repair? Is there a list of likely causes somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

**Endlessly repeating cycles of Windows Installer self-repair may have many different causes.**

Here are a few angles on the subject with the first link providing a long list of possible causes:

- [**How can I determine what causes repeated Windows Installer self-repair?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501028/how-can-i-determine-what-causes-repeated-windows-installer-self-repair/6066263#6066263)
- [Cleanup pending installation](https://serverfault.com/questions/264640/cleanup-pending-installation/276865#276865)
- [What could be causing MsiInstaller to continuously reconfigure applications(EventID 1035)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/43067/what-could-be-causing-msiinstaller-to-continuously-reconfigure-applicationseven)

Comment: Please don't post a list of links as an answer. Even if the resources are on [SE], they might vanish, making this answer worthless.

Comment: Should this question be marked as a duplicate then?

Comment: I can **1)** delete the whole answer, **2)** leave it as it is or **3)** duplicate the content here yielding only a **dual source problem** since I actively try to maintain the content of the article on stackoverflow.com. It is not really a problem for me, I just thought this self-repair issue relevant for both system administrators and developers.